# LibreOffice becomes unresponsive and overloads my CPU when Copying and Pasting text

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, libreoffice

I have a table in LibreOffice which I regularly update. The table currently has 6, 561 words, 45, 255 characters and takes up 39 pages. I don't have any extravagant pictures, just a handful of screenshots of code from a few websites. Recently LibreOffice freezes every time I try to copy text and paste it into this table and if I don't force it to close it sends my CPU into overdrive causing my system to become very loud.

What could be causing this to happen - is LibreOffice not able to handle a table this size?

#### Screenshots below:

[image: non-responsive LibreOffice]

Comment: Just something to keep in the back of your mind: Latex is way more powerful and stable for typesetting complex documents. TexStudio is an excellent environment for working with Latex. These two outperform any WYSIWYG office by a huge margin. Your use case may be the perfect fit for that.

Comment: @ajeh thanks for your input here and on my other question about increasing Linux partition. I am already aware of Latex's power. Thats a major reason I am trying to increase the size of my linux partition. I'm running out of space because I downloaded latex and need additional programs like TeXstudio to use it but I am not really able to until I increase my Linux partition space.